# Count the number of consecutive items in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a dataset like the following:

```
import pandas as pd
d1={'Participant_ID':['P1','P1','P1','P1','P1','P1','P2','P2','P2','P2','P2','P2'],
'Brand_Type':['B1','B1','B2','B1','B2','B2','B2','B2','B1','B2','B1','B1'],
'Date':['5/6/2010','1/27/2010','4/3/2010','7/11/2010','3/1/2010','6/8/2010',
       '5/6/2010','1/27/2010','4/3/2010','7/11/2010','3/1/2010','6/8/2010']}
d11=pd.DataFrame(d1)
d111=d11.sort_values(by=['Participant_ID','Date'])
```

Suppose each participant in the study can consume one of two brands (B1 or B2). I want to create a variable to count how many times in the past they consumed one of the two brands.

This is the output that I want:
[image]

The logic is as follows:

i) For row 1, since there is no prior data, start with 0 in both columns.

ii) For row 2, since the participant consumed B1 in the prior period, **B1_consecutive is 1**, B2_consecutive is zero.

iii) For row 3, since the participant consumed B2 in the prior period, B1_consecutive is 0, **B2_consecutive 1**.

iv) For row 4, since the participant consumed B2 in the prior period, B1_consecutive is 0, **B2_consecutive 2**.

Comment: I have created a code to do exactly what you are looking for, please check my answer

Comment: Thank you so much. I have accepted your answer @ansev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## This is [GroupBy.cumcount](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) +  [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
#sorting data
d111=d11.sort_values(by=['Participant_ID','Date']).reset_index(drop=True)
#Creating count by participant and consecutive Brand
df=d111.copy()
groups=d111['Brand_Type'].ne(d111['Brand_Type'].shift()).cumsum()
df['count']=d111.groupby(['Participant_ID',groups],sort=False).cumcount()+1
#Creating Consecutive_B1 and Consecutive_B2
d111[['Consecutive_B1','Consecutive_B2']]=(df.reset_index()
                                             .pivot_table(index='index',
                                                          columns='Brand_Type',
                                                          values='count',
                                                          fill_value=0) )

d111[['Consecutive_B1','Consecutive_B2']]=(d111.groupby('Participant_ID')['Consecutive_B1','Consecutive_B2']
                                               .shift(fill_value=0) )
print(d111)
```

**Output**

```
   Participant_ID Brand_Type       Date  Consecutive_B1  Consecutive_B2
0              P1         B1  1/27/2010               0               0
1              P1         B2   3/1/2010               1               0
2              P1         B2   4/3/2010               0               1
3              P1         B1   5/6/2010               0               2
4              P1         B2   6/8/2010               1               0
5              P1         B1  7/11/2010               0               1
6              P2         B2  1/27/2010               0               0
7              P2         B1   3/1/2010               0               1
8              P2         B1   4/3/2010               1               0
9              P2         B2   5/6/2010               2               0
10             P2         B1   6/8/2010               0               1
11             P2         B2  7/11/2010               1               0
```

---

## Step by step

- ## 1 Preparing data

---

```
import pandas as pd
d1={'Participant_ID':['P1','P1','P1','P1','P1','P1','P2','P2','P2','P2','P2','P2'],
'Brand_Type':['B1','B1','B2','B1','B2','B2','B2','B2','B1','B2','B1','B1'],
'Date':['5/6/2010','1/27/2010','4/3/2010','7/11/2010','3/1/2010','6/8/2010',
       '5/6/2010','1/27/2010','4/3/2010','7/11/2010','3/1/2010','6/8/2010']}
d11=pd.DataFrame(d1)
```

---

- ## Sorting and  using [`DataFrame.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)

---

```
d111=d11.sort_values(by=['Participant_ID','Date']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

> ## Don't forget reset_index

---

- ## 2 Solution

Now we make a cumulative account grouping by `'Participant_ID'` and by changing in the column `'Brand_Type'`.

## For this we use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html)

```
df=d111.copy()
groups=d111['Brand_Type'].ne(d111['Brand_Type'].shift()).cumsum()
df['count']=(d111.groupby(['Participant_ID',groups],sort=False).cumcount()+1)
print(df)

   Participant_ID Brand_Type       Date  count
0              P1         B1  1/27/2010      1
1              P1         B2   3/1/2010      1
2              P1         B2   4/3/2010      2
3              P1         B1   5/6/2010      1
4              P1         B2   6/8/2010      1
5              P1         B1  7/11/2010      1
6              P2         B2  1/27/2010      1
7              P2         B1   3/1/2010      1
8              P2         B1   4/3/2010      2
9              P2         B2   5/6/2010      1
10             P2         B1   6/8/2010      1
11             P2         B2  7/11/2010      1
```

---

## Now using [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) to create B1_consecutive and B2_consecutive.

```
d111[['Consecutive_B1','Consecutive_B2']]=(df.reset_index()
                                             .pivot_table(index='index',
                                                          columns='Brand_Type',
                                                          values='count',
                                                          fill_value=0) )

d111[['Consecutive_B1','Consecutive_B2']]=(d111.groupby('Participant_ID')['Consecutive_B1','Consecutive_B2']
                                               .shift(fill_value=0) )


print(d111)

   Participant_ID Brand_Type       Date  Consecutive_B1  Consecutive_B2
0              P1         B1  1/27/2010               0               0
1              P1         B2   3/1/2010               1               0
2              P1         B2   4/3/2010               0               1
3              P1         B1   5/6/2010               0               2
4              P1         B2   6/8/2010               1               0
5              P1         B1  7/11/2010               0               1
6              P2         B2  1/27/2010               0               0
7              P2         B1   3/1/2010               0               1
8              P2         B1   4/3/2010               1               0
9              P2         B2   5/6/2010               2               0
10             P2         B1   6/8/2010               0               1
11             P2         B2  7/11/2010               1               0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def count_cumsum(df):

    df = df.copy()

    csum = (df['Brand_Type'] != df['Brand_Type'].shift(1)).cumsum()
    flag = df.groupby(csum).cumcount() + 1
    df.loc[df['Brand_Type']=='B1', 'B1_consecutive'] = flag
    df.loc[df['Brand_Type']=='B2', 'B2_consecutive'] = flag
    df[['B1_consecutive', 'B2_consecutive']] = df[['B1_consecutive', 'B2_consecutive']].shift(1).fillna(0)
    return df
count_cumsum(d111)
```